# Laravel 5.1 and MySQL and backup table

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Is there any way to take backup of a row and all the records from another table that have relation with it, and restore these in Laravel 5.1?
Or I have to write the code by my-self?

Comment: You mean like `mysql_dump`?

Comment: Yes, You have to write the code yourself first.

Comment: @btl no not whole mysql database just row by id and what association with another tables

Comment: @Manmohan_singh I have started to write and I hope to that is a right way :(